# GStreamer 1.0 - mixing audio w/adder or audiomixer renders no output

Tags: gstreamer

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I've been at this for 2 days.  The code looks fine but obviously I'm doing something incorrectly.  I've tried adder on 1.2.4 and audiomixer on 1.7.1.  Debug logs say the pipeline and it's elements are in paused state when the code exits.

```
!/usr/bin/python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject 
from gi.repository import Gst as gst

GObject.threads_init()
gst.init(None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # First create our pipeline

    # filesrc ! mad ! audioconvert ! audioresample          pipe = 
    gst.Pipeline("mypipe")

    # Create the file source 1
    filesrc1 = gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc","filesrc1")
    filesrc1.set_property('location', "test1.mp3")
    pipe.add(filesrc1)

    mad_convert1 = gst.ElementFactory.make("mad","mad_convert1")             
    pipe.add(mad_convert1)
    filesrc1.link(mad_convert1)

    audio_convert1 = gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert","audio_convert1")
    pipe.add(audio_convert1)
    mad_convert1.link(audio_convert1)

    audio_resample1 = gst.ElementFactory.make("audioresample","audio_resample1")
    pipe.add(audio_resample1)
    audio_convert1.link(audio_resample1)

    # Create the file source 2
    filesrc2 = gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc","filesrc2")
    filesrc2.set_property('location', "test2.mp3")
    pipe.add(filesrc2)

    mad_convert2 = gst.ElementFactory.make("mad","mad_convert2")
    pipe.add(mad_convert2);
    filesrc2.link(mad_convert2)

    audio_convert2 = gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert","audio_convert2")
    pipe.add(audio_convert2)
    mad_convert2.link(audio_convert2)

    audio_resample2 = gst.ElementFactory.make("audioresample","audio_resample2")
    pipe.add(audio_resample2)
    audio_convert2.link(audio_resample2)

    # Create a software mixer with "Adder"
    adder = gst.ElementFactory.make("audiomixer","audiomixer")
    pipe.add(adder)

    # Gather a request sink pad on the mixer
    sinkpad1=adder.get_request_pad("sink_%u")

    # Get an another request sink pad on the mixer
    sinkpad2=adder.get_request_pad("sink_%u")

    # .. and connect it's source pad to the previously gathered request pad
    audio_resample1_src=audio_resample1.get_static_pad("src")
    audio_resample1_src.link(sinkpad1)

    audio_resample2_src = audio_resample2.get_static_pad("src")
    audio_resample2_src.link(sinkpad2)

    # Add some output

    audio_convert_out =   gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert","audio_convert_out")
    pipe.add(audio_convert_out)

    output = gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "audio_out")
    output.set_property('location', "test_out.mp3")
    pipe.add(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your output would not be an 'mp3', but raw audio since you don't reencode after mixing.
2. Also I'd recommend to check the return values of all the link() calls
3. And most importantly you never set the pipeline to playing.